# How to fix stored procedure to send file to folder

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to stored procedures.  I have written one that produces good data and I want that data in a report that goes into a folder on my I drive. However, no report generates into that folder. Below is my code.  Thanks for any help.

```
USE [ULTIPRO_ACE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Dependents_Age_26]    Script Date: 3/29/2019 9:54:26 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dependents_Age_26]
AS

if object_id('tmp_UpdateCoverageDate') is not null
drop table dbo.tmp_UpdateCoverageDate; 

create table tmp_UpdateCoverageDate  

(eecempno VARCHAR(MAX), eeceeid VARCHAR(MAX), eepnamefirst VARCHAR(MAX), eepnamelast VARCHAR(MAX), conssn VARCHAR(MAX),
connamefirst VARCHAR(MAX), connamelast VARCHAR(MAX), condateofbirth VARCHAR(MAX), condateofbirth2 VARCHAR(MAX), dbndedcode VARCHAR(MAX),    
dbnbenstatus VARCHAR(MAX), dbndeprecid VARCHAR(MAX), consystemid VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT into tmp_UpdateCoverageDate
select distinct eecempno, eeceeid, eepnamefirst as [EE First Name], eepnamelast as [EE Last Name], replicate('0',9-len(conssn))+conssn as conssn, connamefirst as [Dependent First Name], connamelast as [Dependent Last Name], condateofbirth as DEPDOB, (condateofbirth+9496) as benstpdate, dbndedcode as DEDCODE, dbnbenstatus as [Dep Ben Status], dbndeprecid, consystemid 

from empcomp, contacts, depbplan, emppers 
where eepeeid=coneeid and coneeid=dbneeid and eeceeid=eepeeid and consystemid= dbndeprecid and eecemplstatus in ('A', 'L', 'S') 
and conisdependent = 'y' and ConRelationship='CHL' 
and dbnbenstatus ='a' and datediff(yy, condateofbirth, getdate()) between 25.9 and 26 and (condateofbirth+9490) 
between getdate() and getdate() +7 and dbnbenstopdate is null

select * from tmp_UpdateCoverageDate
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @FileName varchar(100)
    ,@ExportPath varchar(100)
    ,@sCmd varchar(2000)
    ,@v_Servername varchar (32)
    ,@dbname varchar (30)
    ,@Result int

SELECT @v_ServerName = '"' + rtrim(@@SERVERNAME) + '"'
     , @dbname = rtrim(db_name())
     , @ExportPath = 'tmp_UpdateCoverageDate', 'ExportPath'
     , @FileName = convert(char(8),getdate(),112)+'tmp_UpdateCoverageDate' +'.txt'

    SELECT @sCmd = 'bcp ' + @dbName + '.' + ' out "' +
           @ExportPath + @FileName + '" -o"' + @ExportPath + 'ExportLog.txt"' +
           ' -T -S"' + @v_ServerName + '" -c -t'

    PRINT @sCmd

    EXEC @Result = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sCmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Remove the NO_OUTPUT and see whats printed. Bear in mind that the account SQL Server is running under needs write permissions on the destination folder & that the path is local to the server not the client (if they are on different machines)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried this but still no results.  The destination folder is on the server.

Comment: Alex, I'm sorry I just realized that I did not put the output in the comment.  It is below:  NULL
Starting copy...
NULL
7 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 15     Average : (466.67 rows per sec.)
NULL